# How do change background and font color of an Android EditText in Android during editing?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText displaying a user defined text label.
It displays as blue background with white letters.

But when the person clicks into it, I want it to change to white background with black letters, to indicate that it is in edit mode.

Then when the person clicks out of it, I want it to turn back to white on blue, as before. Also, if the entered text was wider than the display, I would like it to left justify.

How can I do all that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try this:

```
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this in the XML layout manager? Also - how to left justify on focus lost?

Answer (score 2):

there are various way to achieved it. like you can do this using textwatcher

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
 // do some operation on text of text1 field
 // do some operation on text of text2 field 
}
```

i am not sure whether you can achieve this in layout . try using selector in layout. might be this can work. for text color use a seperate selector and for edittext background use another selector. format of selector would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

fill desire color in color attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately the xml does not work for an EditText. Also, the TextWatcher doesn't work because this only registers once the user starts typing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with textWatcher as  below

```
 EditText text=new EditText(this);
 text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    //change the color before editing

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //change the color after edited
}
});
```

I think it may helpful to you..

Comment: Not really - this won't change the color until the user starts typing